# Moving Average within N Period in a given Array using Java Code

Tags: java, arrays, moving-average

I just got the question about moving average in one dimension double array. Here is the given array :

```
{ 136.2 , 461.9 , 878.1 , 714.3 , 768.9 , 124.4 , 
  365.4 , 725.1 , 454.4 , 428.2 , 262.6 , 876.7 , 
  452.9 , 382.2 , 295.8 , 245.5 , 817.9 , 207.8 , 
  516.3 , 197.5 }
```

I have to calculate the moving average within n period (n should be input by JOPtionpane). After that I have exist the new array and print the consequence.

For example, for `n=4`, the first period is

```
(136.2 + 461.9 + 878.1 + 714.3) / 4 = 547.625,
```

the second period is

```
(461.9 + 878.1 + 714.3 + 768.9) / 4 = 705.8
```

... etc and the last period is

```
(817.9 + 207.8 + 516.3 + 197.5) / 4 = 434.875
```

I got stuck on this code from here :

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int Period;
    double Average;
    String PeriodString;

        PeriodString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Input any integer", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Period = Integer.parseInt(PeriodString);

        double a[][] = { { 336.0, 441.0, 378.0, 174.0, 168.0, 170.0, 355.0, 225.0, 354.0, 418.0},  
                      { 232.0, 312.0, 432.0, 382.0, 255.0, 255.0, 417.0, 203.0, 216.0, 157.0} };

        DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        if (Period > 0)
        {
            Average = (double) a / Period;


            }

}
```

Comment: I am NOT exactly clear on the question, so for example, If the input is 4, what should be the output ?

Comment: Well, you haven't actually written any code that performs any calculation, or even loops over the input.  You are expected to make _some_ attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: The original question seems to be based around a one-dimensional array. (I don't quite think the phrase translates when you said a *one dimension double array* - so perhaps redefine or clear this up to make more sense). However in the code you 180 (aka pick something else than a one-dimensional array) into a two-dimensional array and don't define what's suppose to happen with that. Should each array be treated with a single cumulative average variable? their own variable? Please lookup the [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question.